# Create partitioned with move partitioned data from original table

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I have big size of database almost 500GB and i just wanted to retain 1 years of data from some large tables and move others data to a different location, So I am trying this by creating partitions on table by date and time. After creating the partition, I can see the partitioned schema in the storage folder and I can also see the original data in the main table.
Is there any way to move the data from the original table while creating a partition or only option is to archive the data.
Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Sure, you can move the data to a different filegroup, but this is a size-of-data operation. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2442/move-data-between-sql-server-database-filegroups/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but when you create partitioned indexes on the main table using the partition scheme, data are moved to the filegroups as specified by the scheme.